# Non capturing groups within named groups

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I want to match one of a collection of strings with a prefix or suffix e.g.

`the color is red`
`red is the color`

I want to match groups `color: red`

So my first attempt was the obvious

`(?<color>(?:the color is )(red|green|blue)|(red|green|blue)(?: is the color))`

I was expecting this to match one group `color: red` but it matches `color: the color is red, 2: red`

I have also tried with the `(?>)` atomic operator

I tried moving the prefix / suffix groups outside of the named group:

`(?:the color is )(?<color>red|green|blue)(?: is the color)`

But this will only match strings with the prefix *and* suffix e.g. `the color is red is the color`. Maybe I could use the lookahead or lookbehind operators with this?

I cannot use the `(?J)` modifier as the regex engine I am using (python `re` module does not support this.

Comment: If you're using PCRE you can try by [branch reset group](https://regex101.com/r/tfsDji/2). The non capturing group looks like wrong use as it does just ensure, that the stuff inside get's not captured (no group output/no group index)

Comment: Are you after `(?<=the color is )(?:red|green|blue)|(?:red|green|blue)(?= is the color)`? See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y9zeR7/1). Do you really need the named capturing group?

Comment: @bobblebubble No, OP uses Python. But PyPi regex supports a lot of features, even the identically named capturing groups.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is a distilled example. In reality there are a number of other groups and I would rather have named groups than rely on indexes.

Comment: Then use PyPi regex module. See https://rextester.com/NRXPIV89625

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not manage to use non capturing groups inside named groups, but at least this correctly extracts `red` as `group('color')`:

```
m = re.search(r"(?P<color>((red|green|blue)(?= is the color)|(?<=the color is )(red|green|blue)))", t)
```

Comment: Thanks Serge, the title was a bit of a misnomer, but this solution works.